# Lighting for Home Office

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

I was wondering what kind of setup would be the most appropriate for my situation? I currently have a room that I am using as a home office and is being illuminated by a single dome light which is not bright enough for my needs.

I'd like to ideally have some sort of LED solution that could crank out a lot of "lumens" and at first looked at LED panels but unfortunately it seems that most of them would require extra wiring for the 0-10V dimmer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For an office, yellowish 2700K light is not ideal. I like 4000-5000K color temperature LEDs a lot better, especially with lots of lumens and high CRI.

I used these [LED strips](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32948777264.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.27426c37Qp70IZ) in suitable aluminium profiles, along with a 24V Meanwell power supply, [remote controlled dimmer](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32810682137.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.27426c37Rjr3Pa) and corresponding [remote](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005002889860706.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.11aa7a7bXR5yB3) (the round one) because I didn't want to install extra wires. The "puck" remote is quite nice and it has a wall mount, so it also acts as a wireless switch. They also make a [power supply](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005001510938378.html) with integrated dimming controller. This manufacturer uses PWM dimming at 5 kHz, so there is no visible flicker. It is also possible to adjust CCT with the remote, if you use two colors of LEDs, but that doubles the number of LEDs and therefore the cost.

LED strips efficiency is worse than with LED panels, but I couldn't find high CRI panels.

If you want a panel, but don't want to install extra wires for dimming, then you should look for one that has a remote control.

Comment: One man's opinion. Not a bad one, in terms of color temp recommendations, by any means, and similar to my own, but I disagree with the remote - I'd do wiring. And that's why we don't answer opinion based question. You're not wrong, and neither am I.

Comment: Ah well. OP asked for no wires, so...

Comment: I know... In my opinion, that's maybe not the best way to go. But, that's _my_ opinion... ;)

Comment: What if OP has a good reason to not want to do some wiring? lol